# Finite sum of the fractional type

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Some special manipulations involving finite sums. How to solve this sum?

$\displaystyle{\sum_{k=1}^{n}}\frac{1}{4k^2 - 1}$

Comment: Hint 1: the denominator can be factorised. Hint 2: Partial fractions. Hint 3: It telescopes.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Note that
$$\frac{1}{4k^2-1}=\frac{\frac{1}{2}}{2k-1}-\frac{\frac{1}{2}}{2k+1}.$$

Answer (score 0):

The following problem below is for an infinite series, but if you can solve it you may be able to solve your problem above.

1. Let $a_n := b_{n} - b_{n+1}$, for some other sequence $b_n$. Prove that the series $\sum_{n =0}^{\infty} a_n$ converges iff the sequence $b_n$ does.
2. In the case that the sum converges, what is its sum?
3. Use (1) and (2) to show that $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{4k^2 - 1}$ converges and find its sum.